# How do I bypass the cooldown for Ender Pearls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to be able to throw Ender Pearls rapidly like in pre-1.9 versions of Minecraft?

Comment: I'm guessing you could find a mod for that somewhere. A lot of people hate that feature.

Comment: I don't want this enough to go through the trouble of mods though. This there a way to do it in vanilla?

Comment: I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with these mechanics, but what I'm describing should work:
Use a command block system to activate a command upon right-click with an ender pearl (as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5S5X76Fwr64/)), then set the command to a /execute that has the player summon an ender pearl entity slightly above the player's head facing in the direction that the player is facing. That way, when the ender pearl lands, it will act as if the player had thrown it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. Unless you are modded or reverse to a older version.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could see if giving your self the haste potion effect does it? Unless it is on a server then I can't help you I'm sorry.